# ReadLine and Validation

Tags: go

In one file that's in path `/operations/validate`:

```
package operations

import (
   "strings"
)

func CheckEnv(environment string) bool {
   env := strings.ToLower(environment)
   return env == "qa" || env == "dev" || env == "prd"
}
```

In the next file that calls the function:

```
package prompts

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    val "thirsty/operations"
)

// AskEnv prompts for Environment
func AskEnv() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter environment (ex: dev, qa, prd): ")
    environment, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(environment)
    env := val.CheckEnv(environment)
    if !env {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid Argument: No environment found for %s", environment)
        return
    }

    os.Setenv("env", environment)
    fmt.Printf("Environment set to %s", environment)
}
```

During the prompt, I've tried `qa` or `dev` but I keep getting `false` as response. I am not sure why this is occurring and would appreciate any insight provided.

Comment: from the documentation: `ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter`

Comment: @JimB does that mean I will need to parse the delimiter out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bufio.Reader.ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) includes the delimiter in the returned string, so your `CheckEnv` function ends up doing (for example):

```
return "qa\n" == "qa" || "qa\n" == "dev" || "qa\n" == "prd"
```

which is of course never going to return `true`.

You can solve this by using one of the `strings.Trim*`, like [`TrimSpace`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace), to remove the trailing line ending character(s) and other unwanted whitespace, like this:

```
func CheckEnv(environment string) bool {
   env := strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(environment))
   return env == "qa" || env == "dev" || env == "prd"
}
```

Comment: The function is `TrimSpace`

Comment: @JimB forgot the second argument :')

Comment: I would still use `TrimSpace`, since this would still leave a trailing `\r` on windows, and you might as well get rid of any other rogue whitespace while you're at it